# Handling a double click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling

I've been doing a lot of form submission using Ajax now and being used to it than having a normal submission. What's been troubling me is that I always ran with a double submission issue when the user clicks twice the submit button to make sure hey hit it.

One way I handle it is by using a flag:

```
ajaxIsLoading = false; // initiate flag
function listItem() {
  // check if ajax is not loading anymore
  if(!ajaxIsLoading) {
    ajaxIsLoading = true;
    $.post( "/post")
      .done(function( data ) {
       // data successfully submitted
       // set flag to false since post is done
       ajaxLoading = false; 
    });
  }
}
```

One problem I know using this is when your internet connection stops in the middle of it and didn't make through setting the `flag` back to `false`.

What I want to ask:

1. Is this a good way to handle this kind of circumstance?
2. Is it worth to check your network in case it went down so I can set the `flag` back to `false` knowing there's a very little chance it will happen?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of what is the context for your issue, so I will examine the 2 distinct cases I can think to.
Anyway I'm surprised your code doesn't show any data passed along with the POST: this should probably added in both cases below.

1) You said that "the user clicks twice **the** submit button": may be it means that you have **only one button** and "a lot of form submission" are successively done through this **unique** button.
If this is the case, the usually expected advantage of asynchronously processing is of no value here, and the pretty simple solution is to proceed synchronously, like this:

```
function listItem() {
    $.post( {url: "/post", async: false} )
      .done(function( data ) {
       // data successfully submitted
    });
}
```

(this way, no further click will have effect, till process done; also note that we had to change the way we are using $.post(), passing it a plain object as argument)

2) At the opposite, since you have written a function rather than a simple piece of code, you may have a lot of buttons, each one submitting a different form through the same `listItem()` call.
In this case, IMO the simplest way is to pass the button id to your function, that will disable it before launching POST, then enable it when achieved, like this:

```
function listItem(btnId) {
    button = $('#' . btnId);
    button.attr( {disabled:'disabled'} );
    $.post( "/post" )
    .done(function( data ) {
        // data successfully submitted
    })
    .always(function() {
        button.removeAttr('disabled');
    });
}
```

(using `.always()` ensures the button will be enabled even if POST failed or connection breaks)

Comment: Isn't `async` is applicable on `$.ajax()` and not on `$.post()`? Also I believe it's been deprecated on new versions.  But +1 on `.always()`, I've been totally ignoring that before thinking I won't be needing that. Thanks.

Comment: @Robin: `$post()` accepts a plain object, as you may control looking at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ (2nd signature), and nothing says it could be deprecated. Anyway, thanks for the feedback.